# Xcode losing UIKit headers

Tags: xcode

I've just had to re-install Xcode twice on my machine, as it has suddenly had some inbuilt UIKit headers deleted. At random times today, I've had build errors saying that common classes like `UILabel` and `UIButton` cannot be found when building for various platforms.

Digging through Xcode's bundle, I can indeed see that the headers for these classes don't open and are "zero bytes". What could be corrupting these files? I certainly haven't touched them.